# MYSQL update text in column with data from another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Mysql database update question.

I have a table with three fields: `TITLE` and `PARAMS` and `LEVEL`

PARAMS column is a text field: `{action="h3",and other information}`

TITLE column is a text field: `happy`

I need to replace/update the `h3` in the `PARAMS` column with the data from the `TITLE` column

So `h3` will be replaced with the data in the `TITLE` column.

In this example, the `h3` is replaced with `h4`.

```
UPDATE `m3o7x_menu` SET `params` = REPLACE(`params`, "h3", "h4") WHERE `level`='3';
```

What is the correct syntax to change `h4` to the `TITLE` column data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE m307x_menu
SET params = REPLACE(params,'h3',title) WHERE level = '3';`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
UPDATE m3o7x_menu SET params = REPLACE(params, 'h3', 'h4') WHERE level='3';
```

Comment: That is identical to OP's example except you are missing a quote around h4.

Comment: I need to change h4 to the data in the TITLE field. The example replaces all instances of h3 with h4. I need to replace all instances of h3 with the data in the TITLE field.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE m3o7x_menu 
SET params = REPLACE(params, '"h3"', concat('"',title,'"') 
WHERE level='3';
```

Comment: Don't know if this is correct, but it is what I would try first.